# ajax post fails to redirect to action

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

Javascript:

```
$("#containerr").on('click', '#select', function() {
        data = {};
        val = {
               "name": 'John',
               "id": 10,
                }
        data.user = JSON.stringify(val);
        data.token = $("input[name=token]").val();
        console.log(data);
        url = '/test/ajax/';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(error);
            },
        });
        return true;
    });
```

PHP:

```
public function ajax()
{
       $input = $this->input->post();
       print_r($input['user']);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
       <input type="hidden" name="token" value="8sdf243dfa426b2sfwe434fdg43gwsf" />
       <button type="submit" id="select">Select</select>
</div>
```

Description:

When i click the select button, i see the the result of the post action. The `print_r($input)` in the php function also returns the desired result. However, as i am not using a form to perform this submission, the browser does not redirect to the post action (`/test/ajax/` in this case). I can see the redirect occuring on the firebug console, but the browser does not actually redirect to that link. When i try `window.location = 'http://www.mybaseurl.com/'+url`, i cannot access data anymore, i lose the `data`. How can i redirect the browser to the post action `url` and still retain the `data`?

Edited javascript:

```
$("#container").on('click', '#select', function() {
            data = {};
            val = {
                   "name": 'John',
                   "id": 10,
                    }
            data.user = JSON.stringify(val);
            data.token = $("input[name=token]").val();
            console.log(data);
            url = '/test/ajax/';
            $.post(url, data, function(data) {
            alert('success');
            });
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: you have to redirect via jquery in success callback of ajax

Comment: There is no redirect occurring. You are simply making a post request via Ajax, which essentially holds the POST variables until that request is complete, and then returning the data. If you want the redirect, you need the form.

Comment: if you want to redirect after submitting, there is no sense for using `ajax` at all. just use a standard `hmtl` `<form>`.

Comment: can you tell me how i can do the redirect without losing data? like i said in the description, when i do window.redirect = 'http://www.mybaseurl.com/'+url in the success callback function, i get an empty page. the print_r($input['user']) in the php does not give any information.

Comment: There are like a million questions where the question is the opposite. Funny you are asking this question vice versa. I think the answer you are looking for is already given by @mpriscella.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire point of AJAX is that it doesn't redirect to the URL you define, it just sends data to it. If you want the user to go to the URL after the AJAX call is finished, you may not want to use AJAX. Just use a regular form.

```
<form method="POST" action="/test/ajax">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="8sdf243dfa426b2sfwe434fdg43gwsf" />
  <button type="submit" id="select">Select</select>
</form>
```

edit:

With the data you're sending, the form would actually look like

```
<form method="POST" action="/test/ajax">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="text" name="id" />
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="8sdf243dfa426b2sfwe434fdg43gwsf" />
  <button type="submit" id="select">Select</select>
</form>
```

Comment: got it. but what if i replaced the ajax method with the post method, would your statement about not redirecting to the url still apply?

Comment: Are you talking about the jQuery post method? Because that is really just a wrapper for the ajax method and it would still not redirect to the page.

Comment: i see. but with just a regular form, as in your code above, how would i be able to send all the form data (if i have more input fields) to the action as a json object? because that is what i am trying to accomplish here.